# Which SAS servers are involved in servicing requests from enterprise Guide and DI studio

Tags: sas

Behind the scenes, SAS has the following servers:
1.metadata server
2.Workspace Server
3.Stored Process Server
4.OLAP Server

When we run a macro or a stored process on Enterprise Guide, does it use Workspace Server which internally uses Meta data server and Stored process Server?
When we run an ETL job on DI Studio, which servers service the request?

Answer (score 2):

When you start EG or DI you initially connect to your metadata server.  The metadata server knows who the users are, where the data resides, and how to connect to SAS workspace servers and SAS Stored Process servers.

When you hit the submit button in a project or job from EG or DI, the EG or DI is going to connect to an Object Spawner (daemon) to launch a SAS workspace wherein your SAS code is executed.  Stored Process server is not involved.   SAS metadata server is only involved in checking permissions and helping the client application find its object spawner.

There are a couple of cases where you can touch a Stored Process server.  This typically happens when you ask to run a stored process or convert a job or program to a stored process.  Unfortunately, SAS has made this a bit complicated by allowing a "stored process" to run on either a Stored Process server or a SAS Workspace server.  This is a regrettable name choice, but something we all need to deal with when using this software stack.